# Android Studio - current position - Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I try to set a marker on my MapActivity with my current position. If I use the emulator, the map dont have any marker. If I use my mobile device (API 24), the activity starts for a short time without marker and then the app crashed.
Thank your for your help guys.

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality();
                        str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
            });
        } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality();
                        str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
//        mMap = googleMap;
//        mMap.getMaxZoomLevel();
//        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
//        LatLng posi = new LatLng(100, 100);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posi).title("my position"));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(posi));

    }

}
```

Comment: Can I verify that you're using an emulated device with `Google Play APIs` support?

Answer (score 0):

you should call get location in onMapReady

Remove all the logic of getting location from onCreate and add following code in onMapReady

```
  @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (mMap!=null){
            Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: Map is "+mMap);
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: Map is not "+mMap);
        }
        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
//                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Map button click"+mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {
                    displayLocationSettingsRequest(getContext());
                    latLngs=new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(),mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
                    setLocationName(latLngs);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onMyLocationButtonClick: "+e);
                }

                //check permission
                return false;
            }
        });
        markerOptions=new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-34, 151));
        mMarker=mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code its working for me

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    //buildGoogleApiClient();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //add this here:
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    //LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("New Marker"));
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("New Marker"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant use the @Override Methode onConnected(Bundle bundle). Also I cant use LocationServices.

Comment: add this to your Activity public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

Comment: Ok the app doesnt crash any more but still no marks on the map. I used your code and Android Studio asked for permissionCheck at "setMyLocationEnabled" and Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient); I implemented it but there are no effects